# SQL check in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope you can help me.
I have 2 tables in my MqSQL database.

Table 1.

```
speedywebs_data

cardid
1
2
3
4
```

Table 2:

```
Speedywebs_results
resultid / card1 / card2
1 / 2 / 1
2 / 4 /4
```

my problem is, i want to get all posts in speedywebs_data table, but only cardid's whos not listed in the speedywebs_results cardid1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT speedywebs_data.*
FROM
  speedywebs_data
WHERE
  cardid NOT IN (SELECT card1 FROM Speedywebs_results WHERE card1 IS NOT NULL)
```

or you could use also this:

```
SELECT speedywebs_data.*
FROM
  speedywebs_data LEFT JOIN Speedywebs_results
  ON speedywebs_data.cardid = Speedywebs_results.card1
WHERE
  Speedywebs_results.card1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanna check if a value doesn't exist ?

So use... `NOT EXISTS`.

```
select cardid
from speedywebs_data swd
where not exists (select null
                  from speedywebs_results swr
                 where swr.card1 = swd.cardid)
```